# Minimum number of moves to empty all buckets, which all have same capacity but different amount of water initially. I can only move left to right

Tags: algorithm, math, game-theory

### Problem definition

I have `n` buckets with the same capacity `m`, one next to the other. I can pour water from one bucket to the one to it's right.Tthe goal is to empty them all into another container but only the rightmost bucket can be emptied. They each have a certain initial amount of water `w`, where `0 <= w <= m` and `w` is an integer. You can't do partial moves in the sense that if you have the following case: 6 6 -> 3 9 where you only pour 3, that would not be allowed. If you pour, you have to pour as much as you can, so a legal move would be 6 6 -> 2 10.

What is the minimum number of moves I have to make to empty all of the buckets? The maximum amount of buckets is 1000 and the maximum capacity is 100.

### Examples

#### Example 1

4 buckets capacity 10 with the following amount of water: 4 0 6

The answer would be 4 0 6 -> 0 4 6 -> 0 0 10 -> 0 0 0 which is three moves.

#### Example 2

3 buckets capacity 10, 8 9 3

8 9 3 -> 8 2 10 -> 0 10 10 -> 0 10 0 -> 0 0 10 -> 0 0 0 = 5 moves total

I first tried doing it with different types of algorithms (greedy, dynamic, backtracking, etc) but none seemed to work. I thought I found a pretty intuitive solution but the program that checks these answers tells me it's wrong, so I might be wrong. Another thing is that this program has rejected correct answers previously so I'm not really sure.

### Here is my solution:

Calculate the sum of all of the buckets before each bucket, and then take the ceiling of that number divided by the capacity of the buckets, and then add all of those numbers.

For example: 6 6 6 6 6 -> 6 12 18 24 30

ceil(6/10) ceil(12/10) ceil(18/10) ceil(24/10) ceil(30/10) = 1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 = 11

that is the right answer: 6 6 6 6 6 -> 6 2 10 6 6 -> 0 8 10 6 6 -> 0 8 10 2 10 -> 0 8 2 10 10 -> 0 0 10 10 10 -> 0 0 10 10 0 -> 0 0 10 0 10 -> 0 0 10 0 0 -> 0 0 0 10 0 -> 0 0 0 0 10 -> 0 0 0 0 0 = 11 steps

The logic is that if there are `L` liters of water before a certain bucket, then there must be at least `ceil(L/Capacity)` moves that pass through that position. So far I have tried around 30 test cases and they have all worked. Every time I thought I found a counterexample, I realized I was wrong after trying it out a few times by hand. The problem is that although I am pretty sure this is the right answer, but I have no idea how to prove something like this or I might simply be wrong.

Can someone tell me if this answer is correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sashoalm `Can someone tell me if this answer is correct?` question is here but an asnwer probably will never appear

Comment: The program that checks these questions tells me it's wrong, but sometimes the people who write the answers make mistakes so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but you don't tell if partial moves are allowed (I mean a move such that the source bucket is not emptied and the destination bucket is not fully filled).

Comment: I don't think it will be very efficient - but your problem could be reduced to shortest-path problem on states graph, where vertices are the states of the buckets and each edge stands for one possible pouring.

Comment: Your reasoning looks quite sound: any amount of water must be moved to the next bucket, and this cannot be done in less than ceil(Amount/Capacity) moves. But this is only a lower bound, it doesn't say if there is a legal sequence that achieves it.

Comment: @user3539895 can you pour water partially from bucket

Comment: Using a brute force search, I confirm that your three examples are correct (not allowing partial moves).

Comment: yes you can pour water partially, and my examples are correct. I mean you can pour only 4 if and be left with 2 or something like that, but it still counts as a move like in my example.

Comment: Would be interesting to see if allowing partial moves enables shorter sequences, which I currently doubt. `w` does not need to be an integer, does it ?

Comment: Can you provide an example where you disagree with the "check program" ?

Comment: I misunderstood the question about pouring partially, you can't do partial moves in the sense that if you have the following case: 6 6 -> 3 9 where you only pour 3, that would not be allowed. If you pour, you have to pour as much as you can, so a legal move would be 6 6 -> 2 10. I can't think of any case where a partial pour would be beneficial so I don't think it changes the optimal solution although it definitely changes the time complexity of an exhaustive search. @Yves yes it's a lower bound, but maybe there is always a legal sequence that allows it, which is what I would need to prove.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide examples where my solution fails because the program only tells you if it's right or wrong. It's like one of those "online judges" like uva online judge where you have a problem and you just submit it and it tells you if you get the right answer. Though the solutions are made by professors who I have very little confidence in which is why I am asking here... It's just a practice problem so it's not a big deal but I still want to be sure, I might just have to ask them directly next week when the actual competition runs.

Comment: I am very surprised to see this post being put on hold. The question is stated very clearly: is the "ceil" formula given by the OP correct ? (i.e. the sum of by excess quotients of the prefix sum of the initial amounts over the bucket capacity)

Answer (score -1):

**Here are my findings on the problem**

First thing let's review the game rules:

- **Rule 1:** You can only dispose all of the right-most bucket if it's filled
- **Rule 2:** You can dispose as many liters as you want (up to `10-bucket[i+1]`) from any `bucket[i]` to `bucket[i+1]`

Let's consider the following special cases:

1. **Shifting**: in case of `0, 10, 0, 0, 0` you *shift* the 2nd bucket 3 times before *disposal*
2. **Merge**: in case of `2 4` you can merge 1st bucket to 2nd to get `0 6`
3. **Perfect Merge**: in case of `6 4` you merge to `0 10` getting 2nd bucket full, an optimal perfect merge will leave 0 in the current bucket

**Conclusion:** I suggest the following strategy, **Right-to-Left Sequential Disposal** which is from left to right, take a **Perfect Merge** and **Shift** it to disposal.

*Note: this is not an optimal algorithm for this problem*

```
void solution (int bucket [], const int size)
{
    for (int i=size-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        // find a non-empty bucket
        if (bucket[i] > 0)
        {
            // bucket need to be filled
            if (bucket[i] < 10)
                for (int j=i-1; j>=0; j--)
                {
                    // -------------------
                    // fill bucket[i] from previous
                    //        buckets and count moves
                    // -------------------

                    if (bucket[i] == 10)
                        break;
                }

            bucket[i]=0; // (size-i) shift + 1 dispose
            moves = moves + (size-i) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Few points that can influence the design of right algorithm :-

> 1. rightmost full buckets are directly disposable. Just need to add n*(n+1)/2 for n rightmost buckets for total steps.
> 2. if rightmost bucket is not full then check the previous bucket if it is full or is able to fill rightmost then do else try to fill that
>      bucket do this recursively till either condition is met or first bucket
>      is reached. Then pour the bucket into next till it is full or other is
>      empty bottom up and count steps.
> 3. Do 1 to 2 till only 1 or no bucket is left
> 4. if one bucket is left then empty it.

Examples :-

```
given 4 0 6 

1. fails 
2. last bucket is not empty hence try to pour second last but it is also empty 
   pour 4 into bucket 1 and then bucket 1 into bucket 2 . Hence after this step  
   4 0 6 => 0 4 6  => 0 0 10
3. 1 bucket left so 4
4. empty bucket 0 0 10 => 0 0 0




 given 8 9 3

   iteration 1 : 8 9 3 => 8 2 10 
   iteration 2 : 8 2 10 => 8 2 0  and  8 2 0 => 0 10 0
   iteration 3 : 0 10 0 => 0 0 10 => 0 0 0


 given 6 6 6 6 6

   iteration 1 : 6 6 6 6 6 => 6 6 6 2 10 
   iteration 2 : 6 6 6 2 10 => 6 6 6 2 0 && 6 6 6 2 0 => 6 2 10 2 0 => 6 2 2 10 0
   iteration 3 : 6 2 2 10 0 => 6 2 2 0 10 => 6 2 2 0 0 && 
                 6 2 2 0 0 => 0 8 2 0 0 => 0 0 10 0 0  
   iteration 4 : 0 0 10 0 0 => 0 0 0 10 0 => 0 0 0 0 10 => 0 0 0 0 0
```

**Time complexity :-** Straight forward implementation would be `O(n^2)` because in 1 iteration atleast 1 rightmost bucket is emptied in `O(n)` computation.

Comment: what if it was something like 2 4 0 4? wouldn't this algorithm do: 2 4 0 4 -> 2 0 4 4 -> 2 0 0 8 -> 0 2 0 8 -> 0 0 2 8 -> 0 0 0 10 -> 0 0 0 0 = 6 steps, but it can be done in less: 2 4 0 4 -> 0 6 0 4 -> 0 0 6 4 -> 0 0 0 10 -> 0 0 0 0 = 4 steps. Or what about 8 9 4? the best solution is 8 9 4 -> 8 9 0 -> 8 0 9 -> 8 0 0 -> 0 8 0 -> 0 0 8 -> 0 0 0 = 6 steps, but with your algorithm it would take longer: 8 9 4 -> 8 3 10 -> 1 10 10 (just wasted two steps, the rest is the same) = 8 steps. Maybe I misunderstood your algorithm?

Comment: @user3539895 no it will do 2 4 0 4 => 0 6 0 4 => 0 0 6 4 => 0 0 0 10 => 0 0 0 0 read 2. step carefully you will get it

Comment: @user3539895 the second one is right . But you  can always check that case you dont need to transfer anything and see if it produces smaller solution.